# Why is there an unwanted space in this typewriter function?

Tags: javascript

This outputs `L oading` however when i execute this, no compilers errors whatsoever, im so confuzzled, i know how to solve this (just put a space before) but i want to know why its happening

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    var i = 0;
    var txt = 'Loading';

    function type()
    {
      if (i < txt.length) {
        document.body.innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
        i++;
        setTimeout(type, 50);
      }
    }
    type();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're modifying the body element before it's done rendering.  If you wait to start typing until after the page has had a chance to fully load (by calling your first type in onload), it will work as expected.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    var i = 0;
    var txt = 'Loading';

    function type() {
      if (i < txt.length) {
        document.body.innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
        i++;
        setTimeout(type, 50);
      }
    }
    window.onload = function() {
      type();
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```